# Apt-get wants to install different version of dependencies for libboost-all-dev?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, apt

When I run `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` I get this error, which seems very common.

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-context-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-coroutine-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-exception-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-graph-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-graph-parallel-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-locale-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-log-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-math-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-mpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-random-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-signals-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-timer-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After digging a little bit deeper and trying to install dependencies individually, I first tried `sudo apt-get install libboost-context-dev` which prompted me to install `libboost-context1.54-dev` which results in the error

```
 libboost-context1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3) but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
```

It seems to me like the dependency asks for a different version than is available through apt-get on my system, but I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Possible duplicate: [Dependency failure while installing libboost-all-dev on ubuntu core 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958570/dependency-failure-while-installing-libboost-all-dev-on-ubuntu-core-14-04)

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this directly - I ended up installing boost from source and that worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the problem with the exact same package but it is a recurrent problem. I have solved the problem (installing `libboost-all-dev`) using the following methodology. It is a bit tedious but works fine in around 5 to 10 minutes (depending on the number of dependancies). 
In fact, you had almost done all the way to the solution.

For each package in your list of unmet dependencies, you have to follow the dependency until you find the package which can not be installed because it has another more recent package available. Then you force its installation in a downgraded version using the `=` sign with `apt-get`. For example in your case:

```
apt-get install libboost1.54-dev=1.54.0-4ubuntu3
```

Once you have done all dependencies, you will be able to install your primary package (`libboost-all-dev`).

I do not know if there is a better (faster) way to do it.